# CGWindowListCreateImage creates image with 4 bytes per pixel. How to change that to 3 bytes per pixel?

Tags: c, xcode, macos, cocoa

The screen capture you get from calling CGWindowListCreateImage is an RGBA image.

How do I force it to return an image in RGB format (3 bytes per pixel) ?

Thank you !!!

Answer (score 1):

`CGImage` does not support formats without an alpha channel. Even `kCGImageAlphaNone` just means "ignore the alpha bits."

If you want a 24-bit image format, you will need to convert it yourself. vImage has routines to do this efficiently. For example, you can convert ARGB to RGB with [`vImageFlatten_ARGB8888ToRGB888`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/performance/Reference/vImage_conversion/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/vImageFlatten_ARGB8888ToRGB888).